# How can I rewrite the following rust code using anonymous lambda function?

Tags: rust

I have following code in rust and this one i working. Here i define fuinction that mutates the argument passed by reference.

```rust
fn inc (v: &mut i32){
    *v+=1;
}

fn main() {
    let mut n = 0;
    // let mut inc = || n += 1;

    inc(&mut n); // call the closure to increment n
    println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 1"

    inc(&mut n); // call the closure again to increment n
    println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 2"

    inc(&mut n); // call the closure again to increment n
    println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 3"
}
```

I tried using a named function instead of an anonymous one (the first example in my question)

in the code example above I have function inc than at takes argument by reference and increments it. Is it somehow possible to define anonymous lambda instead that will do the same task? Ideally it would to have something similiar to the following code to be working:

```
fn main() {
    let mut n = 0;    let mut inc = || n += 1;

    inc(); // call the closure to increment n
    println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 1"

    inc(); // call the closure again to increment n
    println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 2"

    inc(); // call the closure again to increment n
    println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 3"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not possible if you also want to be able to have access to `n` in between, as the closure has exclusive access while it's being used.

Comment: You can pass `n` to the closure with a `&mut` parameter like you did with the function.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it borrowed as mutable all time the closure is alive, and not
> just when called?

```
let mut inc = || n += 1; // captures a mutable reference to n and creates a closure that can mutate it
```

The closure also needs exclusive access to n, just like the inc function. Therefore, it treats the mutable reference as borrowed for the lifetime of the closure, even if the closure is not called immediately.

One solution is, since you are taking no parameters to your lambda function, take one reference parameter. We cannot borrow n as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable in your code example. Here's a lambda function that "mutates a variable passed by reference" [**Playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bd219e5ce4f288ffcb9c7a388b168136):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut n = 0;

    let inc = |v: &mut i32| {
        *v += 1;
    };

    inc(&mut n);
    println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 1"

    inc(&mut n);
    println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 2"

    inc(&mut n);
    println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 3"
}
```

Comment: Their first snippet has this signature: `fn inc (v: &mut i32)` -- indicates the argument. OP just want a lambda function and they don't know the syntax of it, so their "something like this" is "let mut inc = || n += 1;"

Comment: Yes, but `let mut inc = || n += 1;` is without arguments, and without an argument, we cannot borrow `n` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Comment: Agreed, i've phrased it wrong. Edited.

Comment: "The problem is, you are taking no parameters to your lambda function, we cannot borrow n as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable"? This is not a correct sentence.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks. How is it now?

Comment: Now it's better, but you still do not explain the actual problem: why it is borrowed as mutable. Also, it is somewhat incorrect to say "The problem is, you are taking no parameters to your lambda function" - _the solution_ is to make `n` a parameter, but it is not the problem itself that it is not.

Comment: "why it is borrowed as mutable?" Because of the function signature in OP's snippet we first explicitly borrowing as a mutable: `fn inc (v: &mut i32)`

Comment: Yes, but this part works. Why is it borrowed as mutable all time the closure is alive, and not just when called?

Comment: Edited as well.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're fine with taking `n` as a parameter. But in case you really, like, *must* capture it in the closure, you can use [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/):

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;

fn main() {
    let n = Cell::new(0);
    let inc = || n.set(n.get() + 1);

    inc(); // call the closure to increment n
    println!("n = {}", n.get()); // prints "n = 1"

    inc(); // call the closure again to increment n
    println!("n = {}", n.get()); // prints "n = 2"

    inc(); // call the closure again to increment n
    println!("n = {}", n.get()); // prints "n = 3"
}
```

Or for more complex types where [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) isn't enough, you can use [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html):

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let n = RefCell::new(0);
    let inc = || *n.borrow_mut() += 1;

    inc(); // call the closure to increment n
    println!("n = {}", n.borrow()); // prints "n = 1"

    inc(); // call the closure again to increment n
    println!("n = {}", n.borrow()); // prints "n = 2"

    inc(); // call the closure again to increment n
    println!("n = {}", n.borrow()); // prints "n = 3"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't borrow the reference like that, instead you can define the lambda and pass the mutable reference to it like below:

```
fn main() {
    let mut n = 0;
    let inc = |n_ref: &mut i32| {
        *n_ref += 1;
    };

    inc(&mut n); // call the closure to increment n
    println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 1"

    inc(&mut n); // call the closure again to increment n
    println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 2"

    inc(&mut n); // call the closure again to increment n
    println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 3"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Following code using unsafe mutable static [works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021):

```
static mut n: i32 = 0;

fn main() {
    unsafe fn inc() {
        n = n+ 1;
    }

    unsafe {
      inc();
      println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 1"
    } 
    unsafe {
      inc();
      println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 2"
    }
    unsafe {
      inc();
      println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 3"
    }
}
```

`inc` function can be separate from main also:

```
static mut n: i32 = 0;

unsafe fn inc() {
        n = n+ 1;
    }

fn main() {
    unsafe {
      inc();
      println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 1"
    } 
    unsafe {
      inc();
      println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 2"
    }
    unsafe {
      inc();
      println!("n = {}", n); // prints "n = 3"
    }
}
```

Edit: However, `unsafe` should not be used for trivial reasons like incrementing a number, as pointed out by @SilvioMayolo in comments below. Above code is only to show what is possible.

Comment: "Function to increment a number by one" is an extremely questionable reason to bring in heavy machinery like `unsafe`.

Comment: I fully agree. It was just for information and illustration. I will clarify in the answer.